# How to protect Flask-RESTful with Flask-USER management?

Tags: python, rest, authentication, flask, roles

I have a set of User roles laid out and protected on web page side with Flask-User. Now I want to allow them to make REST calls to my API which will be divided using `@roles_required` to filter requests. How to do REST login and pass token\credentials to Flask-USER for `@roles_required` to work?

Answer (score 5):

You must check the repository of [Dillon Dixan](https://github.com/ownaginatious/flask-basic-roles), where he had proposed a very beautiful example, which can help you in achieving your query. Here is the sample code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_basic_roles import BasicRoleAuth
app = Flask(__name__)
auth = BasicRoleAuth()

# Let's add some users.
auth.add_user(user='bob', password='secret123', roles='producer')
auth.add_user(user='alice', password='drowssap', roles=('producer','consumer'))
auth.add_user(user='bill', password='54321')
auth.add_user(user='steve', password='12345', roles='admin')

# Only producers and admins can post, while consumers can only get.
# Admins can also perform all other verbs.
@app.route("/task")
@auth.require(roles={
    'POST': 'producer',
    'GET': 'consumer',
    'DELETE,POST,PATCH,PUT,GET': 'admin'
})
def tasks_endpoint(methods=(...)):
    return "Here tasks get produced and consumed!"

# We can secure by user too. Steve can use any verb on this
# endpoint and everyone else is denied access.
@app.route("/task_status")
@auth.require(users='steve')
def task_status_endpoint(methods=(...)):
    return "Here are the task statuses!"

# Alice, Bill and users with an 'admin' role can access this, while everyone
# else is denied on all verbs.
@app.route("/task_failures")
@auth.require(users=('alice', 'bill'), roles='admin')
def task_failures(methods=(...)):
    return "Here are the task failures!"

# Everyone including unauthenticated users can view task results.
@app.route("/task_results")
def task_results(methods=(...)):
    return "Here are the task results!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

All you need to do is install the library `flask_basic_roles` using `pip`.
Rest you can check in the example and certainly will help you.

In addition, you can also visit and see: https://github.com/raddevon/flask-permissions
Kindly read the flask permission from here : https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/.